# Connecting to RedisToGo through Node.JS

Tags: node.js, redis

I'm using Redis To Go in combination with the https://github.com/mranney/node_redis library. Redis gives me a url that looks like `redis://me:978287c0b670694673d045f08b2e0371@icefish.redistogo.com:9393` but I don't know how to use it as `createClient()` only takes the host and the port.

Comment: You shouldn't be posting your real REDIS URL around the web. Unless you don't care about the privacy of the data inside of course.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

I believe that the scheme for the URL you have is:

`redis://username:password@host:port`.

I don't believe `username` is used. `node_redis` provides two methods that you'll use to log in: `createClient` and `auth`. There are details in the [readme](https://github.com/mranney/node_redis), but for reference  here is the relevant portion:

> ### redis.createClient(port, host, options)
>
> Create a new client connection.  `port` defaults to `6379` and `host`
>   defaults to `127.0.0.1`.  If you have `redis-server` running on the
>   same computer as node, then the defaults for port and host are
>   probably fine.  `options` in an object with the following possible
>   properties:
>
> - `parser`: which Redis protocol reply parser to use.  Defaults to
>     `hiredis` if that module is installed. This may also be set to
>     `javascript`.
> - `return_buffers`: defaults to false.  If set to `true`, then bulk
>     data replies will be returned as node Buffer  objects instead of
>     JavaScript Strings.
>
> `createClient()` returns a `RedisClient` object that is named `client`
>   in all of the examples here.
>
> ### client.auth(password, callback)
>
> When connecting to Redis servers that require authentication, the
>   `AUTH` command must be sent as the first command after connecting. 
>   This can be tricky to coordinate with reconnections, the ready check,
>   etc.  To make this easier, `client.auth()` stashes `password` and will
>   send it after each connection, including reconnections.  `callback` is
>   invoked only once, after the response to the very first `AUTH` command
>   sent.

Comment: Thank you so much! The huge trip up for me was I didn't realize that long chain was the password (rather, I tried inserting my accounts password!). My final code looks liked this: `var redis = require('redis'), client = redis.creatClient(9393, "icefish.redistogo.com"); client.auth("9efv34fcfdfdfdf", function() {console.log("Connected!");});`

Comment: Also see http://blog.jerodsanto.net/2011/06/connecting-node-js-to-redis-to-go-on-heroku/

Answer (score 10):

I also had to add the parameter no_ready_check: true to the call to redis.createClient().

```
client = redis.createClient(settings.redis.port, 
                            settings.redis.host, 
                            {no_ready_check: true});
if (settings.redis.password) {
  client.auth(settings.redis.password, function() {
    console.log('Redis client connected');
  });
}
```