# connecting to RedisToGo on Heroku thru Nodejs

Tags: node.js, heroku, redistogo

I am connecting to redis on localhost using:-

```
 var redisClient = require('redis').createClient({
     host: 'localhost',
     port: 6379,
     db: 0,
     pass: 'RedisPASS'
   });
```

How do i connect to RedisToGo on heroku. I'm using node.js I have gone thru [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7290118/connecting-to-redistogo-through-node-js) but cdn't follow much.

```
var redisClient = require('redis').createClient({
    host: 'http: //abc.com',
    port: 9344,
    db: 0,
    requirepass: 'abc1234'
  });
```

The above does not work.

Where `port no. 9344` and requirepass details i got from RedisToGo app details.

Comment: You have all the answers you need in that question. Dupe.

Comment: @YuvalAdam its not a duplicate, the question there does not pertain to heroku.

Comment: Heroku is irrelevant to this question. You have a Redis URL connections string, and you want to feed it to your client. The exact specification of how to do it is in the answers there.